# Replace ' ' for '-' inside imploded query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this piece of code that gets all subcategories for my article and includes them as CSS classes

```
<article class="{{ strtolower($a->subcategories->pluck('name')->implode(' ')) }} article-item">
```

Where $a is an Article model.

This works great except in case one of the categories having multiple words (a recent petition by my client).

Example:

Categories: 'home', 'ofice' and 'archive and storage'.

**What I get:**

```
<article class="home office archive and storage article-item">
```

**What I want:**

```
<article class="home office archive-and-storage article-item">
```

I hope with this my request is clear, how do I implode multiple words for each of my categories? I've tried to implode and str_replace() on various parts of the query builder but I can't get it right.

Comment: What's your query?

Comment: I thought it was clear? I guess query wasn't the right word. I want to replace spaces for dashes on individual category names. That is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtolower(implode(" ", str_replace(" ", "-", $a->subcategories->pluck('name')->all())));`

This may not look too well, but it should work. At least, it worked for me with array `["a", "b a"]`  (producing "a b-a" output).

Maybe it can help you?

Comment: Hi Danielius, unfortunately this gets me an implode(): Invalid arguments error. I guess it's because $a->subcategories->pluck('name') is an array instead of a String

Comment: @TianRB maybe now?

Comment: Perfect! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need to map category name with spaces to that with dashes. With Laravel collections it's super easy. Just do:

```
{{ strtolower($a->subcategories->pluck('name')->map(function ($c) { return str_replace(" ", "-", $c); })->implode(' ')) }}
```

More on collection you can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections)